# How to store thread-specific data in C++ globally?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I need to store some data in each thread, but since I'm going to access it in multiple places, I can't just use `extern thread_local`. I was wondering if there is an approach to somehow store some data in the current thread, something like this:

```
auto data = std:this_thread::my_data;
```

I know this is not a standard C++ API and this_thread does not have any field to store custom data. But I need something similar to that.

(For those who wondering why I need this, in summary, I am designing a scheduler around LibTorch (PyTorch's C++ API), and I need to know in specific parts of LibTorch's API which CUDA Context I have assigned to that specific thread since I have multiple threads running in parallel each using a different CUA Context. I'm currently using cuCtxGetCurrent() but the problem is that it adds not that negligible overhead and also causes some synchronization problems when called from multiple threads.)

UPDATE:
Since there is a misunderstanding, let me explain in more detail why I can't use thread_local. As I mentioned, I'm designing a scheduler for LibTorch. Imagine this simple example:

```
CUcontext ctx;
cuCtxCreate(ctx, 0, 0);
cuCtxSetCurrent(ctx);
auto stream = at::cuda::getStreamFromPool(false, 0);
at::cuda::setCurrentCUDAStream(stream);

Tensor output = mod->forward(input);
```

Now, forward is a function implemented in the LibTorch backend and already compiled. And there are tons of inner PyTorch functions called inside forward. Somewhere in the backend, I want to know which CUDA Context and Stream I have selected but using thread_local I can't do it. It might be possible, but not that easy and straightforward. So, as mentioned earlier, I need something like `std:this_thread::my_daya` to have global access anywhere.

Comment: "_but since I'm going to access it in multiple places, I can't just use extern thread_local_": I don't understand what the problem with `thread_local` would be?

Comment: Maybe you could explain _why_ you can't use `thread_local`. What happened when you tried? After all, the whole point of thread_local is to store thread-specific data globally so that it can be accessed from multiple places.

Comment: OK, I will add an update to explain why I can't use it.

Comment: "UPDATE: Since there is a misunderstanding, let me explain in more detail why I can't use thread_local. As I mentioned, I'm designing a scheduler for LibTorch. Imagine this simple example:

CUcontext ctx;
" - How does that explain why you can't just use `thread_local`? I don't get it.

Comment: "...  the problem is that it adds not that negligible overhead ..." - Are you compiling *everything* with compiler optimizations *enabled* (possibly even LTO - Link Time Optimizations)? That often turns significant overhead into *insignificant* overhead.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Read it now, the one you read was not the complete update.

Comment: @JesperJuhl No. I do profile it using nsys and noticed that cuctxgetCurrent not only takes a considerable amount of time to return but also called from multiple threads at the same time sometimes it gets stuck for much longer than it's supposed to.

Comment: @AmirFakhimBabaei If you are not testing code compiled with optimizations enabled, then you are wasting your time. Unoptimized builds of C++ code can be extremely slow - 10x or 100x in some cases. Don't benchmark unoptimized builds.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's not my problem. My problem is synchronization delays happening when multiple calls are made at the same time. I don't want to be forced to call to CUDA API every time I need to know which context I am using in the current thread. I don't need other optimizations, that's a different story.

Comment: @AmirFakhimBabaei - So what you want is a `std::mutex` ?

Comment: No! That's not my problem. I am using a heavy call (compared to atomic operations) to know which context has been set in the current thread. Even if there is no synchronization problem, it's still a heavy call for my case.

Comment: I'm not following how your hypothetical `std::this_thread::my_data` differs from defining `extern thread_local auto my_data = foo;` in some namespace, and then simply referencing `my_namespace::my_data`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::thread` constructor expected a callable: `thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );`. There are many approaches how to share thread's `my_data` between other threads. A canonical approach is passing `my_data` by reference in `args`:

```
int my_data = 0;
std::thread thread([](int& my_data){ my_data = 1; }, std::ref(my_data));
thread.join();
std::cout << my_data << "\n";
```

Another approach is using a callable object:

```
struct my_thread {
  int my_data = 0;
  void operator()() { my_data = 1; }
};

my_thread this_thread;
std::thread thread(std::ref(this_thread));
thread.join();
std::cout << this_thread.my_data << "\n";
```

Comment: This is so basic stuff, my problem is much more complicated than this. I'll add an update.

Answer (score 0):

You define a data somewhere and pass it by ref to your thread constructor. Do whatever you'd like your thread worker to perform and you can use it again and again in other places.